# How to fix my program crashing?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a code for projecteuler.net's 7th problem and I kind of succeeded but i need to find the 10001st prime number and what happens is my program crashes if i try to find higher number than 2262 so I'm unable to get the answer I need. I've tried changing int to other data types such as long but that doesn't seem to be a problem here and I'm just stuck now. What do I need to do for my program to not crash when I try to go beyond 2262nd prime number?

```
int main()
{
int numbersList[10000], prime[10000], rez;
int where1=1, where=0;
bool remainder;
prime[0] = 2;

for(int i = 2; i < INT_MAX; i++)
{
    numbersList[where] = i;//2
    where++;
    for(int j = 0; j < where1; j++)
    {
        if(i % numbersList[j] != 0)
        {
            remainder = true;
        }
        else
        {
            remainder = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(remainder)
    {
        prime[where1] = i;
        where1++;
    }
    if(where1==2262)// Which primary number you want. More or equal to 2263 crashes.
    {
        rez = prime[where1-1];
        break;
    }
}
cout << endl << where1 << " primary number: " << rez << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are going way out of bounds of your arrays. You are not checking if `j`, `where` or `where1` are less than 10000. INT_MAX will be larger than 10000 on most platforms.

Comment: I just debugged this in Visual Studio. The program did crash at `numbersList[where] = i;//2` and I was correct in my first comment. `where` was over 10000 leading to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has a small typo.
Modulus operation will be done using `prime` array instead of `numberList` array

```
int main()
{
int numbersList[1000000], prime[100000], rez;
int where1=1, where=0;
bool remainder;
prime[0] = 2;

for(int i = 2; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    numbersList[where] = i;//2
    where++;
    remainder = true;
    for(int j = 0; j < where1; j++)
    {
        if(i % prime[j] != 0)
        {
            remainder = true;
        }
        else
        {
            remainder = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(remainder)
    {
        prime[where1] = i;
        where1++;
    }
    if(where1==10001)//104743
    {
        rez = prime[where1-1];
        break;
    }
}
cout << endl << where1 << " primary number: " << rez << endl;
return 0;
}
```

I am running first for-loop till `10^6` which will be enough to give first `10001st` prime. There are `78489` prime from `1` to `1,000,000` numbers.For more details on numbers of prime you can refer this [link](https://primes.utm.edu/howmany.html)

Comment: This line is still a problem `numbersList[where] = i;//2`  although not needed now.

Comment: Yeah it will able to store `1,000,000` numbers.

Comment: Not with this `int numbersList[10000]` and if you increased the limit you may get a stack overflow. Although again `numbersList` is not used in your updated code.